# VBA VLOOKUP for range to pull associated values

Tags: excel, vba, vlookup

been tinkering with this code and have had no luck so far.

I need the MRN variable to equal the selected Combobox (cbPSID) on a previous user form. This variable is then used to look upon a table to pull adjacent cell "option" to be listed by the lbDOB. I am able to convert the MRN variable into a double, but it returns incorrect numbers. When I debug print the MRN variable it is correct upon entering into the vlookup but gives incorrect value returns if used as a double.

ON another userform user input a date like 01/01/2000 into the cbPSID. If the MRN is kept as a string I receive error code "run-time error '1004': unable to get the vlookup property of the worksheetfunction class". But if I convert MRN into a double instead of a string then the function completes resulting in 34480.

```vb
Sub Dates()                                                                           
    Dim MRN As String                                                                 
        MRN = Selection.cbPSID.Text                                                          
    Set myrange = Worksheets("TranRegistry").Range("A3:F40000")                    
        Debug.Print MRN                                                                       
    Dim match As Long                                                               
        match = Application.WorksheetFunction.VLookup((MRN), myrange, 3, False)                                              
        lbDOB.Caption = match                                                                              
End Sub
```

Comment: Looks to me like `MRN` is a string, not a double. Edit your question, post a data sample of no more than a dozen rows, explain the expected result and show what you get instead.

Comment: More of a stylistic question... you use the dimension `match` for a `VLookUp()`, when you could use `Match()` for the specific column, or `Find()` across a larger area.  Any particular reason?  Given the options, `Match()` for a specific region should be the fastest of the approaches listed... keeping in mind that you're not working with a terribly large number of data, so the time variance should *feel* unnoticed.